# No such file or directory when running maven pipeline

Tags: pipeline

I am trying to run a maven pipeline in Jenkins, and I have configured already the maven settings in Jenkins -> tool configuration. However, [! [maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhz84.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhz84.png) the maven build is resulting to failure. The maven build stage is successful but the .war file is not generated that is why on the "war package copy" stage it resulted to failed stage during runtime. What would be the possible reason?